# Can't take configuration value in view at 2.5.3 version?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, scala-template

@play.Play.application.configuration.getString("application.host")

how can I take configuration value in view at 2.5.3 version?

Note that the view is used everywere. So I'm searching solution without setting parameters in all controllers.

Comment: And what is the problem here? Are you trying to get rid of deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import play.api.Configuration

val config = Configuration.load()
val mode = config.getString("application.host", defaultValueString)
```

the document is https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.3/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration

Good luck with you